# Modules "Pandas" and "Numpy" not found in Pycharm Python Code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm

I tried to use "Pandas" and "Numpy" in my PyCharm IDE but i get an Error:

> ```
> import pandas
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
> ```

I installed the modue with CMD Line with "pip install" as usually.
It is also in the ritght folder of site-packages.
My System is Windows 10 and i have other packages installed this way like "PIL"
with no problems.

Any Solutions? I am thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you could be installing the package for the wrong version of Python, depending on your particular installation.

You may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910393/5935396

Comment: Thx for you help, but the problem was, it was not listed under packages in the Project Interpreter. Needs to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. It was correctly installed but PyCharm does not include the modules on its own. It has to be done manually:

In PyCharm:
File >> Settings >> Project Interpreter

If the modul is not listed under "Package" it has to be installed with clicking on "+" even if it is installed correct via "pip install".